# How to calculate elapsed time in php

Tags: php, time

ive did a search on here and google but cant find anything similar, is there a way to see how long a certain process takes in php?

im running zend_lucene and want to output how long it takes for the search results to be displayed to the user.

Comment: Look to the right for multiple examples of how to do this -->

Comment: Thanks, simple and effective way!

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest this:

`microtime()` returns current Unix timestamp with microseconds

so you can get the microtime before executing your search and then re-get it at the end of the operation. Then you can simply subtract the `end_time` with `start_time` and you get how long took your search.

```
// get the time in microseconds before your search
$start_time = microtime(true);

/**
 * your code here
 * 
 */

// get the time in microseconds when you search is done
$end_time = microtime(true);

// finally subtract and print the time elapsed
echo $start_time - $end_time;
```

hope this helps :-)

Comment: Worth noting (copy-paste from the docs): _This function is only available on operating systems that support the `gettimeofday()` system call._

Answer (score 1):

$elapsed_time : will contain the execution time of the script in seconds

```
$time_start = time();

//your code

$time_end = time();

$time_elapsed = $time_end - $time_start;
```

Comment: It is advisable to add some explanation to your code - what it does, how it works, etc.  In your case, it would be useful to describe what `$time_elapsed` will contain at the end.

Comment: I'm editing the answer

Comment: The execution time will not be unix timestamp - it will be in seconds.  `$start_time` and `$end_time` will be unix timestamps, which are number of seconds since 01/01/1970.  When you subtract one from the other, you'll get number of seconds.

Comment: Also note that if the script takes less than a second, you'll get 0.  If you want to get more precise measurement, you'll need to use `microtime` function (which is not available on all systems)